# DocuSign - Date Format of Data Signed Tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I've logged in to my DocuSign Sandbox Admin Account and have set the Signing Settings > Document Formatting > Current Date Format as follows:

[image]

and saved these changes.

I then created a brand new envelope via the API and sent it and when I view the signing page online it shows the Data Signed as follows:

[image]

I was expecting it to display as `16/9/2021` as per the changes to the signing settings

Is there something else that can override this or explain my the `Date Signed` is showing in the wrong format for my saved signing settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked out the issue here. I had changed the settings in my DocuSign Admin account thinking this would apply to all users of my account,  but it looks like if I authenticate when sending an envelope via the API as a different user it will use the settings for that user's account.

I had read somewhere that you need to make this change in the DocuSign Admin  account but it looks you need to make the change for any account that you might authenticate with when sending envelopes via the API.